# React hooks useState Array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried looking for resetting `useState` array values in here but could not find any references to array values.

Trying to change the drop down value from initial state to allowedState values. I am using hooks method here to set the values using `setStateValues`. If I comment that line of code, it displays the drop down. I could not understand why cannot I use `setStateValues` method to reset the state variable values.

I am getting this following error:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Is there something wrong in here?

```
    import React, { useState } from "react"; 
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

    const StateSelector = () => {   
    const initialValue = [
    { id: 0,value: " --- Select a State ---" }];

      const allowedState = [
        { id: 1, value: "Alabama" },
        { id: 2, value: "Georgia" },
        { id: 3, value: "Tennessee" }
        ];

      const [stateOptions, setStateValues] = useState(initialValue);  
      // initialValue.push(...allowedState);

      console.log(initialValue.length);

      setStateValues(allowedState); // Not sure why cannot I reset the state in here for an array.

         return (<div>
          <label>Select a State:</label>
          <select>
            {stateOptions.map((localState, index) => (
              <option key={localState.id}>{localState.value}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>   ); };

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<StateSelector />, rootElement);
```

Comment: You're essentially setting state which causes a rerender, which sets state, which rerenders, etc.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should not set state (or do anything else with side effects) from within the rendering function. When using hooks, you can use `useEffect` for this.

The following version works:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const StateSelector = () => {
  const initialValue = [
    { id: 0, value: " --- Select a State ---" }];

  const allowedState = [
    { id: 1, value: "Alabama" },
    { id: 2, value: "Georgia" },
    { id: 3, value: "Tennessee" }
  ];

  const [stateOptions, setStateValues] = useState(initialValue);
  // initialValue.push(...allowedState);

  console.log(initialValue.length);
  // ****** BEGINNING OF CHANGE ******
  useEffect(() => {
    // Should not ever set state during rendering, so do this in useEffect instead.
    setStateValues(allowedState);
  }, []);
  // ****** END OF CHANGE ******

  return (<div>
    <label>Select a State:</label>
    <select>
      {stateOptions.map((localState, index) => (
        <option key={localState.id}>{localState.value}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </div>);
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StateSelector />, rootElement);
```

and [here it is in a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/93456l21np).

I'm assuming that you want to eventually load the list of states from some dynamic source (otherwise you could just use `allowedState` directly without using `useState` at all). If so, that api call to load the list could also go inside the `useEffect` block.

Answer (score 9):

Try to keep your state minimal. There is no need to store

```js
   const initialValue = [
    { id: 0,value: " --- Select a State ---" }];
```

as state. Separate the permanent from the changing

```js
const ALL_STATE_VALS = [
    { id: 0,value: " --- Select a State ---" }
    { id: 1, value: "Alabama" },
    { id: 2, value: "Georgia" },
    { id: 3, value: "Tennessee" }
];
```

Then you can store just the id as your state:

```
const StateSelector = () =>{
  const [selectedStateOption, setselectedStateOption] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Select a State:</label>
      <select>
        {ALL_STATE_VALS.map((option, index) => (
          <option key={option.id} selected={index===selectedStateOption}>{option.value}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>);
   )
}
```

Comment: This is not equivalent in functionality, this shows `-- Select a State --` on every subsequent menu opening whereas the original implementation only shows it initially.

Comment: @AvinKavish, I don't understand what you mean. Looking at Ryan's demo the " --- Select a State ---" doesn't show at all and could be omitted. Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Oh yeah, I just assumed that since it was called intial value, it would behave like so. My answer shows an implementation where _select a state_ shows up initially but disappears and cannot be re-picked.

Comment: @AvinKavish, cool. By the way, it seems you were notified about my new ansewr. How comes? I would like to use this solution as well.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Ryan's answer:

Whenever setStateValues is called, React re-renders your component, which means that the function body of the `StateSelector` component function gets re-executed.

React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() will always lead to a re-render unless
>   shouldComponentUpdate() returns false.

Essentially, you're setting state with:

```
setStateValues(allowedState);
```

causing a re-render, which then causes the function to execute, and so on. Hence, the loop issue.

To illustrate the point, if you set a timeout as like:

```
  setTimeout(
    () => setStateValues(allowedState),
    1000
  )
```

Which ends the 'too many re-renders' issue.

In your case, you're dealing with a side-effect, which is handled with `UseEffect`in your component functions. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer shows the correct way to setState but it does not lead to a well functioning select box.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"; 
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const initialValue = { id: 0,value: " --- Select a State ---" };

const options = [
    { id: 1, value: "Alabama" },
    { id: 2, value: "Georgia" },
    { id: 3, value: "Tennessee" }
];

const StateSelector = () => {   
   const [ selected, setSelected ] = useState(initialValue);  

     return (
       <div>
          <label>Select a State:</label>
          <select value={selected}>
            {selected === initialValue && 
                <option disabled value={initialValue}>{initialValue.value}</option>}
            {options.map((localState, index) => (
               <option key={localState.id} value={localState}>
                   {localState.value}
               </option>
             ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      ); 
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StateSelector />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

use state is not always needed you can just simply do this

```
let paymentList = [
    {"id":249,"txnid":"2","fname":"Rigoberto"}, {"id":249,"txnid":"33","fname":"manuel"},]
```

then use your data in a map loop like this in my case it was just a table and im sure many of you are looking for the same. here is how you use it.

```
<div className="card-body">
            <div className="table-responsive">
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Transaction ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            paymentList.map((payment, key) => (
                                <tr key={key}>
                                    <td>{payment.txnid}</td>
                                    <td>{payment.fname}</td>
                                </tr>
                            ))
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//get value
 const valor1 = event.target.elements.valor1.value;
//add to value object
        const todo = {
            valor1,
        }
//push to new value or your state
        setValor(prevLista =>{
            return prevLista.concat(todo)
        })
     
    }
```