# React useEffect don't change state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-functional-component

I had read a lot of answers of questions about it, but it didn't helped me.
Functional component need once subscribe to events and get data from API to state.
**But state don't changes correctly.**

```
const [games, setGames] = useState(null);
const [activeGame, setActiveGame] = useState(null);
const [pending, setPending] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (games === null) {
        setPending(true);
        API.Game.get({}).then((res) => {
            if (res.success) {
                console.log(res.msg.games) // Returning array of games [{...}, {...}]

                setGames(res.msg.games);
                setActiveGame(res.msg.activeGame);

                // Rendered games, but didn't changed state :/
                setTimeout(() => console.log(games), 1000) // Returning null (initial state)
            }
            setPending(false);
        });

        API.Socket.emit('subscribe', 'game');
        API.Socket.on('addGame', (game) => {
            setGames((games) => [...games, game]);
        });
        API.Socket.on('open', (isReconnect) => {
            if (isReconnect) API.Socket.emit('subscribe', 'game');
        });
    }
}, [games, pending, activeGame]);
```

Depending on answers you provided, I tried this, but it still don't work.

```
const [games, setGames] = useState([null]);
const [activeGame, setActiveGame] = useState(null);
const [pending, setPending] = useState(false);

const fetchGames = async () => {
    setPending(true);
    const res = await API.DurakGame.get({});
    if (res.success) {
        setGames(res.msg.games);
        setActiveGame(res.msg.activeGame);
    }
    setPending(false);
    return true;
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchGames();

    API.Socket.emit('subscribe', 'durak');
    API.Socket.on('addGame', (game) => {
        setGames((games) => [...games, game]);
    });
    API.Socket.on('open', (isReconnect) => {
        if (isReconnect) API.Socket.emit('subscribe', 'durak');
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: after setGames, games value still is null

Comment: State updates with hooks are not just async but are also affected by closures and hence you don't see the updated value in the same render cycle even if you add a setTimeout. Please check the duplicate for more detailed explanation and a solution

Comment: It didnt help me. I tried a lot of variations, depending on this question before creating this one. This question dont solve the problem.

Comment: There is no problem, the state is updated, its not just seen in the same render cycle. If you log the state in useEffect with a dependency on games, you will see the update

Comment: No update of state. Also I provided the state into other component in render. Several code lines up it renders, but providing empty array to other component.

Comment: Did you try and add `useEffect(() => {
  console.log(games);
}, [games])` in your component by following the second approach. It definitely will show you the update

Comment: Yes, but how to move this state into component in render? <Display games={games} /> it don't work.

Comment: It will work, you can log the prop in display component directly, it will show the update. It will be null initially since your useState is initialised with null but will update in the next render

Answer (score 0):

Possibility that problem can be caused by :

1. Maybe API function that you is used is async ?

    If yes, useEffect parameter callback is **not async** and **can't be async** maybe :D. [Reference React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tips-for-using-effects).

   **Solution :**
   You can use sperate function API async and call on useEffect function. 
   Maybe you can refer on this link [Example For useEffect async](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/handling-api-calls-using-async-await-in-useeffect-hook-990fb4ae423)
2. The data state updated is Array types 
   State data type is immutable, that means you can't modify directly on the state (Different allocation memmory). And array type is one of data type that if the variable is assigmented on other can have different allocation. 
    So you should be destruct the data for manipulating the data that can be same allocation. 
   [React State with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824116/react-hooks-usestate-array)

I hope that answered your question. Thanks before

Comment: I made edits on question, look, but it dont work

Comment: Ouh ok bro, sorry for my bad answers. Can u try convert to class component ?

Comment: The class component will solve this I think, but I don't wanna use them

Comment: Maybe in class component it's work, i have experienced something like that and i try to convert class component. And it's work

Comment: Ouh, ok bro. Maybe other experienced user can be anwsered :)

Comment: Yes, I hope, but someone closed my question with mark of copy, but I had read ALL questions and this too, before creating my