# React Native - Manage CheckBox states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to make a Quiz App.

Questions are checked after user presses Submit button.

So questions are checked **all at once** in the end.

I need to **save user choices** (answers) for **each question** and then later check them on submit.

**I was thinking about this:**

```
let [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
let [userAnswers, setUserAnswers] = useState([] as any);

  function answerClick(value: any, key: any) {
    // console.log('answer clicked');
    userAnswers[currentQuestionIndex][key] = value; 
    // TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userAnswers[currentQuestionIndex][key] = value')
  }
```

My checkbox for each possible answer in the question:

```
<BouncyCheckbox
   key={index}
   onPress={(value) => {
      answerClick(value, index);
   }}
   text={answer.title}
/>
```

But I get

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userAnswers[current][key] = value')
```

on Answer click

What is **setUserAnswers()** equivalent of **userAnswers[currentQuestionIndex][key] = value**?

Why am I getting undefined error?

How to do this, please help my head hurts.

Comment: have you tried using a debugger inside your `answerClick` function to see what is coming through?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just wanted to point out that *"How to do this, please help my head hurts."* Isn't recommended in SO questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to access a non existing index in the array.

```
userAnsqers = [];
currentQuestionIndex = 0;
// userAnswers[currentQuestionIndex] === undefined
```

What are you attempting to do is adding an `{}` to the array lazily (only when needed). This will work:

```
function answerClick(value: any, key: any) {
  setUserAnswers(latest => {
    const out = [...latest];
    while (out.length <= currentQuestionIndex) out.push({});
    out[currentQuestionIndex][key] = value;
    return out;
  })
}
```

*There is nothing equivalent to `setUserAnswers()` for `userAnswers[currentQuestionIndex][key] = value` ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824116/react-hooks-usestate-array)). You may find som custom hooks to manage arrays or build your own.*

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I remember user choices for each question. So when I go to 3rd question, old choices should be there. I cannot put `isChecked={userAnswers[current][index]}` on my checkbox element because on render I get the same undefined error.

Comment: `isChecked={userAnswers.length > current && userAnswers[current][index]`

Comment: But you should consider providing more context so we can give you a more solid answer

Comment: Thank you again. I made a sandbox. Please take a look at it. It's not working properly. UserAnswers apply to all questions, they are not per question (unique).
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-hellman-4nym1?file=/src/App.tsx:3037-3046

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-ellis-num8e (read `disableBuiltInState` documentation of `BouncyCheckbox`, either you manage `isChecked` or let it to the checkbox. In which case you will be facing with React recycling components)

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `userAnswers` should have the key and values of everything you're trying to change. The reason you're getting undefined is because you're trying to target an object in the `userAnswers` array which can't be found. Also, you are modifying the `userAnswers` state directly and that's really wrong. That's what the `setUserAnswers` is for. You can do this instead.

```
function answerClick(value: any, key: any) {
    // console.log('answer clicked');
    setUserAnswers([
        ...usersAnswers,
        {[key]: [value]}
    ]);
  }
```